# Meteor subscription exception "must use ordered observe"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

i'm getting this error trying to query a mongo collection that has an index on it.

```
Exception from sub articles id SW67ztza4q2xnWtT7 Error: must use ordered observe (ie, 'addedBefore' instead of 'added') with skip or limit
    at [object Object]._.extend.observeChanges (packages/minimongo/minimongo.js:325:1)
    at Function.Mongo.Collection._publishCursor (packages/mongo/collection.js:312:1)
    at [object Object].LocalCollection.Cursor._publishCursor (packages/minimongo/minimongo.js:245:1)
    at [object Object]._.extend._publishHandlerResult (livedata_server.js:1065:13)
    at [object Object]._.extend._runHandler (livedata_server.js:1038:10)
    at [object Object]._.extend._startSubscription (livedata_server.js:842:9)
    at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.sub (livedata_server.js:614:12)
    at livedata_server.js:548:43
```

my problem is that i'm not using `articles.observe` or `articles.observeChanges` anywhere in my code!

i am stumped on this one.

this is the index i created on the collection:

```
db.articles.createIndex({'refIds':1, 'date.published':1})
```

where `refIds` is an array of mongo id strings.

and my query is this:

```
Articles.find({refIds: refId},{
      fields: {
        refIds: 1,
        title: 1,
        author: 1,
        description: 1,
        url: 1,
        date: 1,
        thumbnail: 1
      },
      limit: 20,
      sort: {'date.published':-1}
    })
```

Comment: Meteor index support is experimental, so try ensuring the index from within Meteor via `Articles._ensureIndex({'refIds':1, 'date.published':1})`. Also, see if you get the same error if you remove `'refIds':1,`, because mongo might not know how to compare arrays of strings to put them in order.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to figure out the problem.

there was a race condition happening when i was piping a subscription from one server to another and then down to the client.  like this:

```
collection owner
     |
subscribing server
     |
client browser
```

the exception was happening in my `Meteor.publish` function on the `subscribing server`.  like this:

```
Meteor.publish('myRefs', function(refId){
  CollectionServer.subscribe('myRefs', {refId})
  return Articles.find({refIds: refId},{
      fields: {
        refIds: 1,
        title: 1,
        author: 1,
        description: 1,
        url: 1,
        date: 1,
        thumbnail: 1
      },
      limit: 20,
      sort: {'date.published':-1}
    })
})
```

this was throwing an error, but only recently- and only in prod.  i finally discovered that there was a race condition happening which is why i didn't see this problem in dev.  the collection in dev was nowhere near the 1M docs the prod collection has.

to combat the race condition, i threw the return into the `onReady` of the server subscription and it seems to have solved the exception i was getting above.

```
const Future = Npm.require('fibers/future')
Meteor.publish('myrefs', function(refId){
  let future = new Future()
  CollectionServer.subscribe('myRefs', {refId}, {
    onReady(){
      future.return(Articles.find({refIds: refId}))
    },
    onError(err){
      future.throw(err)
    }
  })
  return future.wait()
})
```